# angular ng-repeat lookup from another json

Tags: json, angularjs

In the following example I am looping through mgId from one JSON & print mg name using ng-repeat. I have another JSON which has associated users for that mg. How can I print assigned user name for respective mgId inside ng-repeat? Here is http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Ly6q14c/9/
basically I am looping through one JSON & I want to load some values from another JSON based variable in the current loop. I do not want to make changes to controller.

Comment: Please post both json

Comment: Does your JSON have to be in the format it is currently in? It's be much easier if you could have the usernames as an object with `mgId` as the keys so you could just have `usernames[mgId]` in your view. Like this: `usernames = { '1': 'Ajit', '2': 'Abhishek' }` and so on. You could also use arrays of names as the values if there's multiple per id. This is assuming you can't make changes in the controller, otherwise I'd just edit the controller.

Comment: please check this fiddle...somehow I am not able to post the code here, its wrapping my code randomly. http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Ly6q14c/9/

Comment: @Fisso : My developer is not ready to deliver json the way I want. I need to manipulate existing JSON.

Comment: Why can't you make changes to the controller?

Comment: @Fissio : This is part of large JSON & I have derived it to the simplest form. & theres are nested loops which is making it difficult for me. I am also new to angular. If there something like lookup in excel, then it should help me

Comment: You could code up the lookup as a simple function in your controller, then use `[myLookupFunc(x.mgId)]` as the key. I don't think there's a native way of doing what you're asking for in the view only.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div ng-repeat="x in names">
      <div>{{x.name}}
        <span ng-repeat="y in usernames track by $index">
          <input ng-model="y.assignedUserNames" ng-if="y.mgId==x.mgId "></input>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Working [plunker](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Ly6q14c/10/)

Comment: But i do not recommend to solve this problem with this solution. You should create some helper function in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in code..

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl',
  function ($scope) {
        $scope.masterClausesList = 
    [  
{
    "Id":1,
    "ID":1,
    "Title":"Platform",
    "Desc":"Our Platform provides our users with a variety of resources to facilitate organizing of groups, (a \"Meetup\" or \"Meetup Group\"), and creating of a network (\"Meetup Everywhere\").",
    "Checked":null,
    "CCategory":"Company Contracts"
  },
  {
    "Id":2,
    "ID":2,
    "Title":"Membership",
    "Desc":"Our Platform provides our users with a variety of resources to facilitate organizing of groups, (a \"Meetup\" or \"Meetup Group\"), and creating of a network (\"Meetup Everywhere\").",
    "Checked":null,
    "CCategory":"Company Contracts"
  },
  {
    "Id":3,
    "ID":3,
    "Title":"Payment",
    "Desc":"Limited to 100 days",
    "Checked":null,
    "CCategory":"Company Contracts"
  }
];
    $scope.selectedContract = [];
    $scope.selectedContract.clausesSelected = 
    [
     {
        "Id":1,
        "ID":1,
        "Title":"Platform",
        "SortId":null,
        "Desc":"Our Platform provides our users with a variety of resources to facilitate organizing of groups, (a \"Meetup\" or \"Meetup Group\"), and creating of a network (\"Meetup Everywhere\").",
        "CCategory":null,
        "CUSER":null,
        "CCONTRACTHDRID":"6",
        "CCLAUSEMSTID":"1"
      }
    ];

    $scope.kk = '___';



var k2 = [];
angular.forEach($scope.masterClausesList, function (value1,key1) {
  angular.forEach($scope.selectedContract.clausesSelected, function (value2,key2) {
    
  });
});

var log = [];
angular.forEach($scope.masterClausesList, function(value) {
  angular.forEach($scope.selectedContract.clausesSelected, function (value2) {
    if(value2.CCLAUSEMSTID == value.Id){
      value.Checked = true
      this.push(value);
    }else{
     //this.push(value);
    }
  },log);
}, log);

$scope.kk = log;
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{kk}}
  </body>
```